# Homo from hemo?

Tags: language-evolution, vowel

I stumbled upon a Latin grammar from 1916 today, and it mentions that *nemo* comes from *ne* and an old version of *homo*, namely *hemo*.
Is this theory considered valid these days?
What support is there for this earlier form of *homo* beside the first vowel of *nemo*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is still considered valid. The proto-Italic word is reconstructed as **χem-ō*, *χe/om-on-m*. de Vaan has the best summary:

[image]

Comment: +1 for the picture. I hear so much about de Vaan, that it's nice to finally see a page of his!

Comment: @ktm5124: You can find it on-line, it is...around. If not, I could help you.

Comment: Thanks! A general remark: Text in images is not searchable and therefore not as useful as plain text, so I suggest transcribing such texts whenever possible.

Comment: Attentive readers will have noticed that de Vaan actually offers two opposing hypotheses. One is that nemo is ne + hemo, the other that nemo is ne + homo and that hemon(em) is a back-formation from nemo.